# Winforms Custom textbox unable to resize

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have created a custom textbox which only allows numbers but when I use the control on my page I am unable to increase its width. I tried to set the autosize property the control to TRUE but no luck.

The code of the custom text box is mentioned below

```
public partial class NumericalTextBox : UserControl
{
    public NumericalTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.KeyPress += NumericalTextBox_KeyPress;
    }

    private void NumericalTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)(e.KeyChar) == 22)
        {
            IDataObject clipData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            string dataSet = (string)clipData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            foreach (char data in dataSet)
            {
                if (!(char.IsNumber(data)) && !(char.IsControl(data)))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (((char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))) || ((char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me on how to enable resizing of the text Box.

Comment: [How to: Create a Numeric Text Box (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms229644(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: also, if I remember correctly, there could be a difference between a 'keypad number' and a 'keyboard number'

Comment: I cannot inherit Textbox class, I need to inherit Usercontrol class.

Comment: Did you set the anchor of the contained Textbox to fit with the sizechanges of the usercontrol?

Comment: Set text box Dock property to Fill.

Comment: Deriving from TextBox is the correct solution, there is no clue whatsoever why you insist you cannot do this.  As posted, you'll have to add a bunch of code to make it behave like a text box again.  Like OnResize() to get it resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the textbox1 to anchor with the size of the usercontrol? If not it resizes only the NumericalTextBox but not the actual textbox contained in the usercontrol.

```
        textBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
```

If the textbox is the only control you could also just set the dockstyle to fill:

```
textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

The textbox will then automatically enlarge to fill the available space in the usercontrol.

As mentionend in the comments of your question, the correct way to implement a NumericTextbox would be to actually inherit from `TextBox` itself and put your handling code in there. [TextBox is not a sealed class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.TEXTBOX%29;k%28TEXTBOX%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) so I don't see any reasons to not inherit directly from there.

Comment: Thanks for that as well...I am totally new to this thing...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    textBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the custom control set **AutoSize to false** and **maximum height to 20** (same as Textbox Height)
For the **textbox set Dock to Fill**